# Where to store configuration of an elastic beanstalk application?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I create a small nodejs application which run on aws elasticbeanstalk. At the moment the application configuration is store in a json file. I want to create an frontend to manipulate some parts of this configuration and read about MEAN stack. But Amazon has no MongoDB support. So what is the best pratice in aws elasticbeanstalk to handle configurations for an application? To store this in S3 Bucket is very easy but I think the performace is not very good.

Best regards

Comment: Environment variable are at their always best

Answer (score 0):

How much configuration data are you talking about? If it is typical small amount, and it only changes once in a while, but you need it available each time the application restarts, S3 is probably the easiest and cheapest option. Spinning up a MongoDB instance, just to store a small amount of mostly-read-only data is probably overkill. What makes you think the performance is not very good?

Comment: Hi,
I plan to create an web interface to update some parts of my application config and if two users update the configuration at the same time I run into trouble with S3.

Answer (score 0):

AWS usually recommends DynamoDB for such cases, but in this case you are getting vendor lock in. Also choose of the configuration storage depend on requirements how fast new changes need to be applied to the instances?

Good option to use mysql as configuration db, because you avoid vendor lock in, you can deliver configuration changes as fast as they has been applied and in app can be used memcached interface of the mysql.